# PHP variable to Javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently working on making a simple php script to edit certain aspects of a game in JavaScript. When attempting to pass variables from the script to the game using forms, the variable data does not seem to transfer. As of now, the script is meant to edit the RDG value of one player in the game. The code is as follows:

script.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="tron2.html">


<p>What are your player 1's RGB values:
<input type="text" name="color1r" /> Red 
<input type="text" name="color1g" /> Green 
<input type="text" name="color1b" /> Blue </p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the portion of the code in javascript where variables are assigned

```
<?php

$color1r = $_POST["color1r"];
$color1g = $_POST["color1g"];
$color1b = $_POST["color1b"];


?>


<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
        Tron2 
    </TITLE>
    <script>
                    var x = "<?=  $color1r; ?>";
                    var y = "<?=  $color1g; ?>";
        var z = "<?=  $color1b; ?>";
                     //more code for the game
```

When the game runs, the color of the player stays black, so the values of x,y,z must all be 0. Is there any reason why the values aren't being passed?

Comment: `<?=` already implies `echo`. Not sure what `<?= echo` does.

Comment: I removed echo, and it still has the same issue

Comment: If this still isn't working it could be something else.

Comment: To make sure other parts were working properly, I changed the values to regular values between 0 and 255 and the color did change so I do believe the problem is isolated here

Answer (score 6):

```
<form method="get" ...>
```

and

```
$color1r = $_POST["color1r"];
```

are not friends.

`<form method="post" ...>` and `$color1r = $_POST["color1r"];` are friends, and
`<form method="get" ...>` and `$color1r = $_GET["color1r"];` are also friends.

Also `<?= echo` should error. Use `<? echo $string` or `<?=$string`

Comment: I changed the "method = "get"" to "post" but it seems that the problem is still there, nothing changes

Comment: I like your description :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from tangential POST/GET mixup, always use `json_encode()` to output PHP variables in JS code.

`echo` without escaping or other escaping functions will generate invalid and/or insecure code.

```
<script>var jsvalue = <?php echo json_encode($phpvalue) ?>;</script>
```

---

In your specific case:

```
<form method="post" action="tron2.html">
```

and

```
<script>
    var x = <?= json_encode($color1r) ?>;
```

Comment: Why is that needed/how does this fix the problem which is obviously a get/post data mixup?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is not true. echo without escaping or other escaping functions **may** generate  invalid and/or insecure code.

Comment: @popnoodles saying "not true" is a bit harsh; you're pedantic about lucky secure case in a very common most-likely-vulnerable pattern.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 if somebody sends data with value `"; evil_session_hijacking_code(); "` then your site will run attacker's code. There's plenty of non-obvious filter-evading tricks here, but `json_encode()` protects against them all by default.

Comment: I concur with @porneL, Properly escaping the data is important. Outputting unsanitized output in JS code is just as bad as doing it in HTML.

Comment: @porneL if you're not pedantic about programming, you may generate invalid or insecure code.

Comment: otherwise it is a good idea.