# Passing JSON directly to Javascript without JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, json

I noticed that many people are passing objects from PHP to Javascript as JSON like this:

```
var obj=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($obj) ?>');
```

or

```
var obj=jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($obj) ?>');
```

Why don't people pass JSON directly like this?

```
var obj=<?php echo json_encode($obj) ?>;
```

This works fine with the few objects that I tried. Are there cases when this won't work?

Comment: You'll generally find the latter mentioned here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/a/415890, http://stackoverflow.com/a/169035, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14993384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> passing objects from PHP to Javascript as JSON like this:
>
> ```
> var obj=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($obj) ?>');
> ```

Ouch! You're right, this is overcomplicated. Also, it actually has serious problems with apostrophes and backslashes in the JSON string, which are not escaped and destroy the string literal.

> Why don't people pass JSON directly?

People who do it properly do it this way indeed.

> Are there cases when this won't work?

Yes. There are unicode characters that are valid in pure JSON, but a syntax error in JavaScript - see http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset for details. However, `json_encode` would output these as escape sequences anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd use JSON parsers to secure situations where the code returned may be erroneous (instead of crashing your script, it will simply throw an exception and keep going).  This is generally a good idea when the JSON is sent from a source you don't have control over.  It seems unnecessary when you're in control of both ends (PHP server and JS client).

That said, a "safer" method just for server side would be:

```
<?php $json_encoded = json_encode ($obj); ?>
var obj=<?php echo ($json_encoded ? $json_encoded : 'null'); ?>;
```

This makes sure only a valid object is passed into JavaScript.

More info: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/